# Use a TableView on a Flipside template

Tags: ios

I am using a **Flipside** template from Xcode.

I would like to add a Table View on the Flipside view.

I have added the Table View and a Cell view and modified the .h

```
@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController
< ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *mydata;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblVw;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

and in the Flipside.m, i have a button which switches to the main view :

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

It should launch the flipsideViewControllerDidFinish method of the main view but i doesn't work anymore since i have added the Tableview and it's delegate ..

What could be wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Is done being called? Is flipsideViewControllerDidFinish: being called in the delegate?

Comment: when i tap on done, it is called, yes. And if i put a breakpoint on the [self.delegate] line it is called.. but it does nothing .. it worked before putting the tableview and its delegates..

Comment: If you put a log in the implementation of  flipsideViewControllerDidFinish: in the delegate, does it log?

Comment: no it does not log ..  is it because i have several delegates ? i have really big difficulties with delegates :(

Comment: If you log self.delegate in the done method, what does it return?

Comment: - (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
returns null

Comment: note : i'm using a BarButtonItem in a Navigation Bar for "done" action but it worked fine before adding the TableView

Comment: So it appears that you never set the delegate. Whichever object implements that delegate method needs to set itself as the delegate -- I don't know why this would have changed after you added the table view.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a new project with Flipside template. I have copied all code from both viewcontroller, relinked the objects and it works fine now .. I really don't know what was happening.. Probably an error of mine. Thanks